# subversion AD configuration

Tags: svn, active-directory

I have installed subversion on the linux operating system but I am not successful in Active Directory connection.

Action steps

OS: Centos 7

```
1-yum install subversion
2-svn --version 1.7.14
3-yum install mod_lab
4-yum install mod_dav_svn
5-cd /etc/httpd/conf.d/
6-vim subversion.conf
7-vi /var/www/svn/user
8-svnadmin create /var/www/svn/docs
9-chown -R apache.apache /var/www/svn/docs
10-chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www/svn/docs
11-chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/svn/docs
12-service httpd restart

/etc/httpd/conf.d/subversion.conf

<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNParentPath /var/www/svn
AuthzSVNAccessFile /var/www/svn/user
SVNListParentPath On
AuthLDAPBindAuthoritative off
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=administrator,CN=Users,DC=xxxx,DC=com,DC=tr"
AURHLDAPURL "ldap://x.x.x.x:389/cn=user,=dc=xxxx,dc=com,dc=tr?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
AuthLDAPBindPassword "xxxxx"
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthType Basic
AuthName "xxxx"
AuthUserFile /etc/svn-auth-users
Require valid-user
</Location>


/var/www/svn/user

[/]
* = rw

[docs:/]
* = rw
```

As a result of the actions I have made, I can not connect to the active direktory user at all

Comment: what says the apache error log(with debuglevel)?

Answer (score 0):

Httpd error_log :

```
[Thu May 18 08:15:18.375748 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2271] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.475015 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2366] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.475823 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 2366] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using localhost.localdomain. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.494156 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 2366] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.494865 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 2366] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.498230 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2366] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) SVN/1.9.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu May 18 08:15:19.498255 2017] [core:notice] [pid 2366] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu May 18 08:15:41.422674 2017] [auth_basic:error] [pid 2369] [client 192.168.2.145:54289] AH01618: user korkutefe not found: /svn
```